# SQL Query create two column each with different values from two table

Tags: sql-server

I Have to create two-column different value with the same data, important thing data is from combining two tables with the inner join Statement. Here are the table1 and table 2 (it's like attendance report)
Am attaching tables 
Table 1
Create a table

```
    \* table 1 *\
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tsStudAttandance](
        [IDNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [StudentName] [varchar](300) NULL,
        [TrainnerName] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [Date] [date] NULL,
        [InTime] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Weekday] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [OutTime] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [StudListId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_tsAttandance] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [IDNo] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


 /* INSERT QUERY NO: 1 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
1, 'Ms.Eva', 'John', '8/12/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 1, 4.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 2 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
2, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/12/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 3 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
3, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/12/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 4 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
4, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/12/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 5 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
5, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/12/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Monday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 6 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
6, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/12/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 7 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
7, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/12/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Monday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 8 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
8, 'Ms.Sheena', 'Stev', '8/12/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Monday', '9:00 PM', 10, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 9 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
9, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/13/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Tuesday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 10 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
10, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/13/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Tuesday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 11 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
11, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/14/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 12 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
12, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/14/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 13 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
13, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/14/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 14 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
14, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/14/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 15 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
15, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/14/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 16 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
16, 'Mr.Vicky', 'John', '8/14/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '9:00 PM', 7, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 17 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
17, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/14/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 18 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
18, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/14/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 19 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
19, 'Ms.Sheena', 'Stev', '8/14/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '9:00 PM', 10, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 20 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
20, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/15/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Thursday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 21 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
21, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/15/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Thursday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 22 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
22, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/17/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Saturday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 23 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
23, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/17/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Saturday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 24 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
24, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/17/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Saturday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 25 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
25, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/18/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 26 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
26, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/18/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 27 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
27, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/18/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Sunday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 28 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
28, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/18/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Sunday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 29 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
29, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/18/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Sunday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 30 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
30, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/18/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 31 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
31, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/18/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Sunday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 32 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
32, 'Ms.Eva', 'John', '8/19/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 1, 4.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 33 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
33, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/19/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 34 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
34, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/19/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 35 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
35, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/19/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 36 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
36, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/19/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Monday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 37 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
37, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/19/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Monday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 38 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
38, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/19/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Monday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 39 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
39, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/19/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Monday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 40 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
40, 'Ms.Sheena', 'Stev', '8/19/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Monday', '9:00 PM', 10, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 41 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
41, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/20/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Tuesday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 42 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
42, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/20/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Tuesday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 43 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
43, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/20/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Tuesday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 44 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
44, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/21/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 45 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
45, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/21/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 46 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
46, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/21/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 47 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
47, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/21/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 48 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
48, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/21/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 49 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
49, 'Mr.Vicky', 'John', '8/21/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '9:00 PM', 7, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 50 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
50, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/21/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Wednesday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 51 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
51, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/21/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 52 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
52, 'Ms.Sheena', 'Stev', '8/21/2019', '7:00 PM', 'Wednesday', '9:00 PM', 10, 2.00, 1
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 53 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
53, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/22/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Thursday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 54 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
54, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/22/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Thursday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 55 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
55, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/24/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Saturday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 56 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
56, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/24/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Saturday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 57 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
57, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/24/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Saturday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 58 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
58, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', '8/25/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 2, 2.00, 4
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 59 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
59, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', '8/25/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 3, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 60 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
60, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', '8/25/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Sunday', '11:00 AM', 4, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 61 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
61, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', '8/25/2019', '9:00 AM', 'Sunday', '11:00 AM', 5, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 62 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
62, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', '8/25/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Sunday', '7:00 PM', 6, 2.00, 3
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 63 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
63, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', '8/25/2019', '11:00 AM', 'Sunday', '1:00 PM', 8, 2.00, 6
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 64 */
INSERT INTO table_name(IDNo, StudentName, TrainnerName, Date, InTime, Weekday, OutTime, StudListId, Hours, DAYS)
VALUES
(
64, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', '8/25/2019', '5:00 PM', 'Sunday', '7:00 PM', 9, 2.00, 3
);
```

Table 2

```
\* Table 2 *\
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tsStudenList](
    [IdNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [TrainnerName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [StudentRegNo] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Course] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Duration] [smallint] NULL,
    [Schedule] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Days] [int] NULL,
    [StartDate]  AS (CONVERT([date],getdate())),
    [Timing] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tsStudenList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tsStudAttandance]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tsStudAttandance_tsStudenList] FOREIGN KEY([StudListId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tsStudenList] ([IdNo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tsStudAttandance] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tsStudAttandance_tsStudenList]
GO


     /* INSERT QUERY NO: 1 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
1, 'Ms.Eva', 'John', 'TSSR1900001', 'CCNA', 60, 'SAT', 1, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 01:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 2 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
2, 'Mr.John Stev', 'Stev', 'TSSR1900002', 'CCNA', 60, 'SAT-WED', 4, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 01:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 3 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
3, 'Mr.Stev Job', 'John', 'TSSR1900003', 'CCNP', 70, 'SUN-MON-WED', 3, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 11 :00 AM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 4 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
4, 'Mr.Bill Gate', 'John', 'TSSR1900004', 'PHOTOSHOP', 20, 'SUN-MON-WED', 3, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 11:00 AM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 5 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
5, 'Mr.Krish', 'Stev', 'TSSR1900005', 'INDESIGN', 24, 'SAT-THR', 6, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 01:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 6 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
6, 'Mr.Chisty', 'Stev', 'TSSR1900006', 'CEH', 80, 'SUN-MON-WED', 3, '8/12/2019', '11:00 AM - 01:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 7 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
7, 'Mr.Vicky', 'John', 'TSSR1900007', 'CEH', 80, 'WED', 1, '8/12/2019', '05:00 PM - 07:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 8 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
8, 'Mr.Micky', 'Stev', 'TSSR1900008', 'INDESIGN', 24, 'SAT-THR', 6, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 01:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 9 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
9, 'Ms.Victorya', 'John', 'TSSR1900009', 'PHOTOSHOP', 24, 'SUN-MON-WED', 3, '8/12/2019', '09:00 AM - 11:00 PM'
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 10 */
INSERT INTO table_name(idno, studentname, trainnername, studentregno, course, duration, schedule, days, startdate, timing)
VALUES
(
10, 'Ms.Sheena', 'Stev', 'TSSR1900010', 'CEH', 40, 'MON & WED', 2, '8/12/2019', '07:00 PM - 09:00 PM'
);
```

Need a Final Report like this
[image]

Here is the Remark should come to **YES or No** by comparing they Intime and OutTime (By checking the Schedule if SAT-MON-WED means three days, so if the hours are less then 6 Remark Should 'NO'. Like That Should Check Schedule and Time for Remarks) and Percentage of class status Should sum the hours of this week(Sat-Thu) and divide by Duration of the second table. I got That result Week  **But I need overall status** too if I use Where Clauses Between 'Start Date' And 'End Date'.

Here the sample report for YES ON and Discontinued(more than one month is optional) 
[image]
This possibility should be when a student does not attend the class for one month **Discontinued** and in 6days class attended less than or equal to 3 **No**

Most Important Overall Status and Current week Status as the above pic

Here is the Code Which I tried

```
  BEGIN
SELECT tsStudAttandance.StudentName as 'Name', tsStudenList.StartDate as 'Start Date',
CASE WHEN
         sum(
                    case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
            - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)) = CAST(tsStudenList.Duration as float)
Then (SELECT top 1 tsStudAttandance.Date FROM tsStudAttandance ORDER BY  tsStudAttandance.Date DESC)

END as 'End Date',
cast(cast(round(sum(
                    case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
- cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float))
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %' as 'Class Status in %',
(
cast(cast(round(sum(
                    case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
- cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float))
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %'  ) as 'Over Class Status in %', 
tsStudenList.Course as 'Course Name', tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule

FROM tsStudAttandance INNER JOIN dbo.tsStudenList ON tsStudAttandance.StudListId = tsStudenList.IdNo 
GROUP BY tsStudAttandance.StudentName,tsStudenList.Duration, tsStudenList.StartDate, tsStudenList.Schedule, tsStudenList.Course, tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule 

End;
```

Comment: The formatting here is going to chase away a lot of people. Sample data should ideally contain create table statements and insert statements. The query you posted is formatted so painfully it is impossible to see what is going on. And most importantly it is not clear what you need help with.

Comment: The create table statement additions are good.  Now get rid of the html tables and instead give insert statements that operate on the created tables.  That is the best setup for sample data when asking a question.

Comment: That is a pretty useful site. But....I don't want to spend a bunch of time copying and pasting your data to setup the problem so I can then spend time working on the issue. A bit of explanation about the output would help. What is "Discontinued" mean in your output and how do you determine it?

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense what you are trying to do. Your attendance dates are all earlier than the start date for the student. The values "Discontinued" and "On vacation" have no clarity. How do you know somebody is on vacation? Is that big query you posted returning some of the data already and you just need help with part of it?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry For That! Copy Pasted Made That Difference and don't worry about that start date it's just for Sample Reference. I have Got the Week Class Status % If I Use Where Between Dates or if doesn't use where it will give Over All Status But I need both as sperate Column ** weekly & Overall**. Just Only Overall Status is needed. Remark's i created

Comment: How can you do things like determine if a person has been absent for a month if the dates in the attendance table are not valid? Nobody can help you answer this because the sample data is a mess.

Comment: @SeanLange Above i mentioned now clear data, Now needed Column is Over All Status % Column and Regular column (Discontinued and No on Possibilities).  I appreciate your effort. I got the answer that I need But mean while Am expecting some answers. According to your need, I'll rewrite the attendance data and Student List one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the Code for the above Question

```
Use modeldb
 Go   
 BEGIN
    Select a.[SNo],a.Name, a.[StartDate],b.[EndDate], a.[WeekStatus], b.[OverAllStatus],a.[CourseName], a.Timing, a.Schedule, a.Regular FROM
    (SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tsStudAttandance.StudentName ASC) as 'SNo',

tsStudAttandance.StudentName as 'Name', tsStudenList.StartDate as 'StartDate',tsStudenList.StudentRegNo as 'RegNo',

cast(cast(round(sum(
                    case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
- cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float))
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %' as 'WeekStatus', 
tsStudenList.Course as 'CourseName', tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule,

(Case 
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 6    
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                        else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                        end 
                        - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=3

            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 5 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                        else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                        end 
                        - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=2
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 4 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                        else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                        end 
                        - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 3 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                        else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                        end 
                        - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 2
            AND ((sum(case 
                    when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                    then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
                    - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=1
        Then 
            'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 1
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                        else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                        end 
                        - cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'

        ELSE
             'No'
        End)
                As 'Regular'

FROM tsStudAttandance INNER JOIN dbo.tsStudenList ON tsStudAttandance.StudListId = tsStudenList.IdNo Where tsStudAttandance.Date Between '2019-08-12' AND '2019-08-17' GROUP BY tsStudAttandance.StudentName,tsStudenList.Duration, tsStudenList.StartDate, tsStudenList.Schedule, tsStudenList.Course, tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule, tsStudenList.InDays,tsStudenList.StudentRegNo) a
Left join (SELECT tsStudAttandance.StudentName as 'Name' ,
CASE WHEN
         sum(
case 
    when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
    then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime ,2)))as float)
end 
- cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime,2)))as float)) = CAST(tsStudenList.Duration as float)
Then (SELECT top 1 tsStudAttandance.Date FROM tsStudAttandance ORDER BY  tsStudAttandance.Date DESC)

END as 'EndDate',
(cast(cast(round(sum(
                    case 
                        when CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2))) = 'PM' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(' ' FROM Right(tsStudAttandance.InTime , 2))) ='AM'
                        then  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)+12 
                    else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float) 
                    end 
- cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 AM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.Intime , 2)) ) as float))
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %'  ) as 'OverAllStatus' 
From tsStudAttandance INNER JOIN dbo.tsStudenList ON tsStudAttandance.StudListId = tsStudenList.IdNo  Group by tsStudAttandance.StudentName,tsStudenList.Duration) b  on a.Name = b.Name 
END;
```

The above Question records limited to two weeks so if for Month and more then a month We can adjust Case for **Discontinued** in Regular Remark Part.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 is Case to Create Stored Procedure Run Good In SQL, Instead of

> CONVERT We can USE SUBSTRING

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), TRIM(':00 PM' FROM LEFT(tsStudAttandance.OutTime , 2)) ) as float)` Can be Changed to `SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2)` and By Using `SUBSTRING` O9 Will Be Consider as `9` SO we Can USE Replace() and LEN() 
Here is the code that

```
BEGIN
Select a.Name, a.[StartDate],b.[EndDate], a.[WeekStatus], b.[OverAllStatus],a.[CourseName], a.Timing, a.Schedule, a.Regular FROM
(SELECT 


tsStudAttandance.StudentName as 'Name', tsStudenList.StartDate as 'StartDate',tsStudenList.StudentRegNo as 'RegNo',

cast(cast(round(sum(
                    case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                    end
                - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                    )
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %' as 'WeekStatus', 
tsStudenList.Course as 'CourseName', tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule,

(Case 
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 6    
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=3

            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 5 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=2
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 4 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 3 
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 2
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=1
        Then 
            'YES'
        When tsStudenList.InDays = 1
            AND ((sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))/2)>=1
            Then 
                'YES'

        ELSE
             'No'
        End)
                As 'Regular'

FROM tsStudAttandance INNER JOIN dbo.tsStudenList ON tsStudAttandance.StudListId = tsStudenList.IdNo Where tsStudAttandance.Date Between '2019-08-12' AND '2019-08-17' GROUP BY tsStudAttandance.StudentName,tsStudenList.Duration, tsStudenList.StartDate, tsStudenList.Schedule, tsStudenList.Course, tsStudenList.Timing, tsStudenList.Schedule, tsStudenList.InDays,tsStudenList.StudentRegNo) a
Left join (SELECT tsStudAttandance.StudentName as 'Name' ,
CASE WHEN
         sum(case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)) = CAST(tsStudenList.Duration as Int)
Then (SELECT top 1 tsStudAttandance.Date FROM tsStudAttandance ORDER BY  tsStudAttandance.Date DESC)

END as 'EndDate',
(cast(cast(round(sum(
                    (case 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='AM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)+12 
                        when SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.OutTime))) = 'PM' AND SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))-1,len(RTRIM(tsStudAttandance.InTime))) ='PM'
                        then cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                        else 
                        cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.OutTime,1,2),':','') as int)
                       end
                        - cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tsStudAttandance.InTime,1,2),':','') as int)))
/ cast(tsStudenList.Duration as float)*100,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %'  ) as 'OverAllStatus' 
From tsStudAttandance INNER JOIN dbo.tsStudenList ON tsStudAttandance.StudListId = tsStudenList.IdNo  Group by tsStudAttandance.StudentName,tsStudenList.Duration) b  on a.Name = b.Name 
End;
```